# Python 3.4.3: How can I check whether input is within a specified range, and keep asking until it is?

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
size = int(input("put even integer from 2 to 52")
def check(size):
    while size%2 != 0 or (2 <= size <= 52) == False:
          size = int(input("put even integer from 2 to 52")
    return size
check(size)
```

How can I check whether the size input is within 2 to 52 and make the variable size into the number they put.

Answer (score 1):

There're some syntax errors in your code. This should do it:

```
def get_size():
    size = -1
    while size % 2 or not 2 <= size <= 52:
          size = int(input("put even integer from 2 to 52 "))
    return size

size = get_size()
print(size)
```